# popToRootViewController with a tableview occur crash

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabbar with 5 navigationController. I also have a tableView in myViewController. When I try to use self.popToRootViewController in first navigationController's ViewWillDisappear, it will crash. I also push same myViewController in 3 navigationController and use same self.popToRootViewController function in ViewWillDisappear. It work very well. I try to set animated true and false for debug. It both cause crash. The only way to let first navigation controller popToRootViewController function work is upgrade iOS to 13.(iOS 12.4 occur the crash.)

Does somebody know why navigation can't pop a controller with a tableView? The message said UItableView dataSource did not set. It is weird because I can push myViewController well and I think pop means remove element in the stack.

On the other hand, the popToRootViewController function can work well in below function.

```
func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {

     firstNavigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

}

/// Show and hide the tab bar.
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - hidden: To hide or show.
///   - animated: To animate or not.
///   - duration: The duration of the animation.
///   - completion: The completion handler that is called once the animation is completed.
open func setBar(hidden: Bool, animated: Bool,duration: TimeInterval = 0.3, completion: ((Bool)->Void)? = nil) {
    let animations = {() -> Void in
        let safeAreaBottom: CGFloat

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *){
            safeAreaBottom = self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
        }else{
            safeAreaBottom = 0.0
        }

        self.buttonsContainerHeightConstraint.constant = hidden ? 0.0 : self.buttonsContainerHeightConstraintInitialConstant + safeAreaBottom
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    if animated {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: animations, completion: completion)
    }
    else {
        animations()
    }
}
```

logs
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxP5t.jpg

Any suggestion is appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Join the logs crash

Comment: The call stack shows `AZTabBarController.showBar(...)` - can you add this method (as code, not as screenshot) to the question?

Comment: @AndreasOetjen I use AZtabbar to controll my tab bar. https://github.com/Minitour/AZTabBarController

Comment: Hi @AndreasOetjen your comment really perfect. I check my code again and change my code self.currentTabBar?.setBar(hidden: true, animated: false). After I close the animation. It doesn't crash anymore thank you.